# How to setTimeout for my custom toast on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The idea is simple: By the time `showToast` function is executed, I want to set my toast's className to **show**, and then replace it with an empty string to hide it after showing it for 3 secs.

HTML:

```
<div id="toast">New color button added</div>
```

JS:

```
const showToast = () => {
    const toast = document.getElementById('toast');
    toast.className = 'show';
    setTimeout(() => {
        toast.className = toast.className.replace('show', '');
    }, 3000);
};
```

I'm trying to convert this into a React component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Toast = () => {
    const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(true);

    setTimeout(() => {
        setIsShown(!isShown);
    }, 3000);

    return (
        <div className={isShown ? 'show' : undefined}>New color button added</div>
    );
};

export default Toast;
```

And then I'm going to have this in a function by the time I need to show it:

```
<Toast />
```

But I'm not sure if this is correct. I honestly don't know how to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on `React-toastify` [documentation](https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/introduction/) you are able to pass the time by using `autoClose` variable as below:

```
<ToastContainer
position="top-right"
autoClose={5000}
hideProgressBar={false}
newestOnTop={false}
closeOnClick
rtl={false}
pauseOnFocusLoss
draggable
pauseOnHover
theme="light"
/>
{/* Same as */}
<ToastContainer />
```

Or

```
toast(' Wow so easy!', {
position: "top-right",
autoClose: 5000,
hideProgressBar: false,
closeOnClick: true,
pauseOnHover: true,
draggable: true,
progress: undefined,
theme: "light",
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the timeout inside a useEffect for proper execution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).